# C# Application.Current.Dispatcher == null

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь обновить UI из другого потока, все вроде работает, но иногда Application.Current.Dispatcher пуст. Почему? Как решить проблему?

Comment: Точно `Dispatcher = null`, не `Application.Current = null`?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать такую конструкцию
в классе наследуемом от ***Window*** использовать ***this.Dispatcher***

```
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {

        }));
```